# How to change the url of "return to list"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I need to change the return url when you are within an entity page, in particular:

[image]

I would like to include a custom parameter at the end of the url, so I did so:

```
$url = route("content.index") . "?cat=$cat";
$this->crud->setRoute($url);
```

I added this code within `setupCreateOperation` and `setupUpdateOperation` and seems to work well, but the problem is that doing so, also the form url change:

[image]

as you can see the `?cat=$cat` was added after `content`, this will create an issue when storing the content, in particular I get:

> 405 - method not allowed

So, is there a way to change only the link that allow the user to go back to the entity list including a query parameter?

Thanks

Comment: which method that ```route``` has? ```POST``` or ```PUT```

Comment: @matheenulla has post, but the issue is raised when I use `setRoute`, otherwise works well, I just need to change the return url as described in the question

Comment: then you can pass the parameter directly like this? ```route("content.index",['cat' => $cat])```

Comment: @matheenulla as I described in the question, if I change the url the form request is modified too, and then I have the 405 issue

Answer (score 0):

With *Laravel Backpack*, you can achieve this with the `breadcrumbs` attribute.
Please read: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-breadcrumbs#define-breadcrumbs-inside-the-controller

```
$this->data['breadcrumbs'] = [
    trans('backpack::crud.admin') => backpack_url('dashboard'),
    'example' => route("content.index") . "?cat=$cat",
    trans('backpack::base.dashboard') => false,
];
```

Comment: I already saw that, but the problem's that this is not a breadcrumb, it is the dynamic return url generated by backpack